# Haskell: file name and path do not match module name

Tags: haskell, module

I am using the Haskell app for OS X, and have created a Haskell project, and when I create another file in the project, Haskell tells me that the file name and path do not match the module name! I am new to Haskell, what does this mean?

It is telling me also that it is expecting the name of the file as the module name.

Thanks!

Comment: So what is the module name of your module (thats the word that follows `module ` in its source code)? and what is the filename? Please make sure that you copy&paste these answers, because upper/lowercase-issues are important here.

Comment: The name of the .hs file is just NewModule.hs at the moment, as I am just testing things. The file is completely empty.

Comment: the file should contain at least the line `module NewModule;`

Comment: "The Haskell app for OS X" doesn't mean anything. Are you talking about GHC, GHCi, cabal, stack, or something weird?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working with the help of Michael. There is an app on the Mac appstore just called 'Haskell' which is what I use. It's just a Haskell IDE. Sorry for being vague.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message tells you that the module name and the file name should be the same.

E.g.: If the file name is `NewModule.hs`, the module name should be `NewModule`.
E.g.

```
-- NewModule.hs:

module NewModule where

-- you may define functions here...
```

So, you just have to use the `module` directive.

Comment: That didn't work, but I used 'module NewModule where' and it worked. What does the 'where' part mean?

Comment: @manwholikesspritekit `where` introduces a block of declarations. For example when you define a function you can say: `f x y = ... where a = ...` so the `where a = ...` defines some names that can be used in the body of the function. The whole module can be seen as such a block.

Comment: "In particular, there is no connection between module names and file names, and more than one module could conceivably reside in a single file (one module may even span several files). Of course, a particular implementation will most likely adopt conventions that make the connection between modules and files more stringent."
 
 This is from document of GHC, in this case if file name not same as module name, 
 i dont know how GHC will look for file to import when I import module X from file Y.hs.
 
https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/modules.html